# Magento Connect Manager Connect Error: Fail to open a file

Tags: magento-connect

I'm using Magento Community on my Win8.1 with Apache2.

I've been using Magento Connect Manager install a lot of plugins.

I'm trying to install M2E Pro today and I got a problem, which is the error below:

"
Checking dependencies of packages
Starting to download m2epro_ebay_magento-6.2.1.tgz ...
...done: 2,347,484 bytes
Installing package community/m2epro_ebay_magento 6.2.1

CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/magento\downloader.cache\community\m2epro_ebay_magento-6.2.1\app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Block/Adminhtml/Wizard/InstallationEbay/Installation/ModeConfirmation/"

I think the reason is that some settings on my machine cutted off the path of the file...I had a similar problem before, same case: path was too long.

**Update:**

I don't think its permission problem since I installed other plugin successfully before.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The actual directory doesn't exist / wasn't created when unpacking the tar.gz

Comment: Even after manually unpacking, the same problem occurs, can't access the above directory / file and not a permissions issue

Answer (score 2):

check permission of this file.

also you check compilation

Whenever an error message contains includes/src/ it is very likely that the new/updated code has not been compiled yet. To recover from this (especially if your back-end has become unusable) edit includes/config.php

```
define(‘COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’src’);
```

to

```
#define(‘COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’src’);
```

Also you can do for future

1) Turn of Magento Compilation

2) Turn on Magento’s Cache

3) Install the Extension

4) Refresh Magento’s Cache

5) Logout and Again Login

6) Rerun Magento’s Compilation Process

Comment: I dont think its about permission at all. I installed few plugins before... It works... And Its not working on this one.

Comment: Are you install Module after disable Compilation?

Comment: I went to tools->compliation and the compiler status is: disabled